# How to make it so that when you click on ''swap-img " src '' swap -main " changes to the src of the clicked ''swap-img "

Tags: javascript

```js
let swapImg = document.querySelectorAll('.swap-img');
for(let i = 0; i < swapImg.length; i++){
    let show = swapImg[i].closest('.swap-main')
    swapImg[i].addEventListener('click', (e) =>{

        e.target.closest('.swap-main').src = e.target.src
         
    })
}
```

```html
<img class="clothes__img swap-main " id="img__hover " src="img/clothes__img1.jpg" alt="">
<h5 class="clothes__caption">Women's tracksuit Q109</h5>
<div class="clothes__info">
  <p class="clothes__price">$ 38.00</p>
  <form class="form form_margin">
    <div class="form__item">
      <div data-ajax="true" class="rating rating_set">
        <div class="rating__body">
          <div class="rating__active"></div>
          <div class="rating__items">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="1">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="2">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="3">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="4">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="5">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rating__value">3.6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="hover__block" id="di2">
  <div class="hover__iner onlyOne">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="img/clothes__img8.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="img/clothes__img2.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="img/clothes__img3.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="img/clothes__img7.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

this js code is not working, because the fourth line of code doesn't see "swap-main". I'm new to programming, I don't know much, so I hope you can help me with a solution

Comment: Please could you show the js that's not working - currently you have only shown the first line

Answer (score 0):

Check snipper there, from your code javascript to do that:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.swap-img').forEach(e => {
   e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
       document.querySelector('.swap-main').src = ev.target.src;
   })
})
```

I put pictures from lorem picsum to visually have something.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.swap-img').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    document.querySelector('.swap-main').src = ev.target.src;
  })
})
```

```html
<img class="clothes__img swap-main " id="img__hover " src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200" alt="">
<h5 class="clothes__caption">Women's tracksuit Q109</h5>
<div class="clothes__info">
  <p class="clothes__price">$ 38.00</p>
  <form class="form form_margin">
    <div class="form__item">
      <div data-ajax="true" class="rating rating_set">
        <div class="rating__body">
          <div class="rating__active"></div>
          <div class="rating__items">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="1">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="2">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="3">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="4">
            <input type="radio" class="rating__item" name="rating" value="5">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rating__value">3.6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="hover__block" id="di2">
  <div class="hover__iner onlyOne">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200" alt="">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/7/300/200" alt="">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/300/200" alt="">
    <img class="iner__img swap-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/300/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, but I need to change the src of the nearest swap-main, and not the first one in the queue, I thought this solution would work:  document.querySelectorAll('.swap-img').forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            ev.target.closest('.main-img').src = ev.target.src
            
        })
     }) but see null on 3 line of code

Comment: hehe you didn't say you have several swap-main! Regarding your structure , if you have several blocks like that beginning by the img swap-main ending by the div hover block, it'll be a bot tricky. The img swap-main, div clothes_info and div hover_block are at the same level in DOM. From clicked element you have to closest hover_block, go up 2 times (previousElementSibling) to find your swap-main

Comment: I don't quite understand how to implement it in code.

Comment: do you have bigger code? with more elements in